# ionic build ios **export failed** error: exportArchive: Found no compatible export methds

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, xcode7.3

When I run: `ionic build ios` the archive succeeds but the export fails.

Error Messages:

```
error: exportArchive: Found no compatible export methods for: DVTFilePath:0x7f9d3dc41d20:'/Users/**PATH**/platforms/ios/**PROJECTNAME**.xcarchive'

Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "Found no compatible export methods for: DVTFilePath:0x7f9d3dc41d20:'/Users/**PATH**/platforms/ios/**PROJECTNAME**.xcarchive'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found no compatible export methods for: DVTFilePath:0x7f9d3dc41d20:'/Users/**PATH**/platforms/ios/**PROJECTNAME**.xcarchive'} 


Error: Error code 70 for command: xcodebuild with args: -exportArchive,-archivePath,fasTask.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Users/**PATH**/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Users/**PATH**/platforms/ios/build/device
```

I modified the *exportOptions.plist* 'method' key to 'export_method' but same error message.

I tried uninstalling Xcode and re-installing. The first build after re-installation gives me a successful build. Any builds after the first build give me the same error message as before.

Also if I `npm uninstall -g ionic cordova` and delete everything in the platform folder, then `npm install -g ionic cordova` then the first build succeeds but any build after it fails.

`ionic serve` works fine every-time.

Details:

- Xcode 7.3.1
- ionic 2.1.14
- cordova 6.4.0
- cordova-ios 4.3.1
- ios-deploy 1.9.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I am having the same issue, it happened after updating ionic and cordova to the lastest version. I created a new project `ionic start` added platform ios and when trying `ionic run ios --device` i got the same output that you're having after building trying to export.

When running an older (pre-update) project i was not having any problem at all after i did a `ionic platform rm ios` and then `ionic platform add ios` the problem reproduced again. I think is has to be to the way that the updated cli is adding the platform or that it is expecting an updated SDK version (Xcode 8).

A **workaround** is first launch and installing the app to the device using Xcode, then in the terminal do `ionic run ios --device -l` this will create a livereload ionic server. At the end it will show the error but the livereload server will be still working and you can develop and the changes will be reflected on the app without any problem.

Xcode: 7.3.2
Ionic: 2.1.13
Cordova: 6.4

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ionic build ios --emulator
```